# written characters: bèi vs jiàn

Tags: writing, handwriting, calligraphy

I have two books displaying different meannings for characters that look the same to me: What is the difference (if any) among the character for "bèi" (shell, money) and "jiàn" (to see)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look more carefully, you can see that the last stroke is different.

- 贝 bèi ends with a 捺 nà stroke.
- 见 jiàn ends with a 竖湾钩 shùwāngōu, a 'hook'.

Check [this list](http://www.clearchinese.com/chinese-writing/strokes.htm).

Comment: regarding 贝 could it be that 捺 as in 人 has become 点 ？

Comment: @S.Rhee Although in the simplified character 贝 the lower 2 strokes are 人, I don't see why the last stroke would be 点. I would be interested to see anything online that proves that I am wrong and the last stroke is actually a dot.

Comment: ＂教学汉字规范手册＂，汉字的笔画及笔画名称，汉字笔画名称表，第４行：笔画：丶 ，名称：点，例字：小 ，it seems 长点 is still a form of 点，iciba：长点：
Long Dot Stroke

Comment: Actually 见 is a 人 with a big 目 on top, that is 見 in traditional rendering, which is clear from earlier inscriptions. 人 has been replaced with 儿 in both modern scripts.

贝 on the other hand is a simplification of 貝, which is a stylized image of a shell. 人 is present in the simplified version, but not in the traditional.

It is a bit unfortunate, but in reality nobody has any problems differentiate these characters. 已己巳 are tougher in that regard…